# Generate Presigned URL with format: s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm generating presigned urls but its problematic for bucket names with periods and SSL because of the *.s3.amazonaws certificate, as described here:
http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host.html

Is there a way to generate urls with the following format?:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket.name/key

I didn't see an option in the API. I'm guessing I can do it "manually" by rearranging the url, but I'd rather avoid a hack if its not necessary.

Based on Michael's answer here is the code I'm now using:

```
public static URL bucketNameAfterS3Url(URL url) {

    int index = url.getHost().indexOf("s3");
    String host = url.getHost().substring(index);
    String bucket = url.getHost().substring(0, index - 1);
    URL toUse;
    try {
        toUse = new URL(url.getProtocol(), host, url.getPort(), '/' + bucket + url.getFile());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    }
    return toUse;
}
```

Comment: The AWS S3 documentation says this about getBucketLocation() which is needed for this to work properly (see michael's notes): "To view the location constraint of a bucket, the user must be the bucket owner." Because we don't own the buckets (we are just given read permissions), this solution seems untenable, and so we just revert to streaming the file through our servers in the case of periods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any official way to do this, but string manipulation isn't as sketchy as it seems, since the possible patterns are limited.  Bucket names can't contain a slash, and finding the other elements is pretty safe.

One important consideration is the region, and how it impacts the valid combinations of URL.

Consider "lolcat.jpg" in bucket "example-bucket"...

```
https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/lolcat.jpg
https://s3.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/lolcat.jpg
```

These two urls are equivalent *only* if the bucket is in the US-Standard region.

If not, the top one works, but the bottom one will return an error message telling you that you are using the wrong endpoint.

For other regions, you have to use the correct regional endpoint.  If us-west-2, this would actually be:

```
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/example-bucket/lolcat.jpg
```

So, you have to know the bucket's region before you can transpose elements in the URL.

If you are using Signature Version 4, then you already know the region, because it's needed in order to generate the signature.  With Signature Version 2, you can even rearrange the position of the bucket name in the URL *after* signing the URL without invalidating the signature, because of the details of that algorithm.

Comment: I don't know which regions our customers host their buckets, so this sounds problematic. Actually if I manipulated the url, I would request a presigned one first, and rearrange it, but from you say, that sounds just as problematic region-wise... Amazon doesn't have to pass a region qualified url back. Thanks for alerting me to the region issue, I wouldn't have realized it was a problem.

Comment: We will probably just tell our customers not to use periods in their bucket names. Seems odd that Amazon allows it, because of this.

Comment: @Joel the reason the dots are allowed is that if aren't using HTTPS, then you can `CNAME` example-bucket.example.com -> example-bucket.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com and S3 will pick up the bucket name from the `Host:` HTTP header.  The same applies, with a different `CNAME` target, for the S3 [static web site hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) feature... the bucket name has to match the fully-qualified hostname.  Much of the issue is probably related to the way S3 has evolved over the years.

Comment: Also, you can interrogate S3 to *learn* the location of a bucket, explained in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091816/retrieve-buckets-objects-without-knowing-buckets-region-with-aws-s3-rest-api/27092765#27092765

Comment: I hope this doesn't make it sound like I don't appreciate your help, but this _is_ a hack or maybe better stated as a "workaround". The fact that Amazon returns a url they know can't possibly work, even though they have the information to do make it correct (they have the bucket name, they know it has periods, they know what region it belongs to, they know they are returning SSL url...). They really should fix this. Not your fault, and thanks for the help working around their issue.

Answer (score 7):

The S3 client allows you to set an option to configure this:

```
    // Configure the S3 client to generate urls with valid SSL certificates. With this setting we will get urls
    // like https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/... but if this is not set we will get urls like
    // https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/ which will cause the browser to complain about invalid SSL
    // certificates.
    s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(new S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
```

Comment: Do you know if this works with non-standard regions?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by non-standard regions. You can set the region through s3Client.setRegion() method.

Comment: Path style will be deprecated in the future, https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/bk9mfm/s3_path_style_being_deprecated_on_sep_30_2020/ do you have another solution?

Comment: AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
        .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
        .build();