# Amazon S3 Presign URL using dotted bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have the following bucket name `long.bucket.name`. When using the CLI `aws s3 presign`, the URL I get is of the form:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/long.bucket.name/path/to/key?AWSAccessKeyId=123&...
```

When using the `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` Java library, however, the URL I get is of the form

```
https://long.bucket.name.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/key?AWSAccessKeyId=123&...
```

The problem with this URL is the SSL certification fails because of the wild card (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html). If I try to use the same formatted URL `https://s3.amazonaws.com/long.bucket.namae...` the signature validation fails

```
 The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method
```

The only thing I can do is to use `http` which is not ideal. How can I generate a Presign URL correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29652193/generate-presigned-url-with-format-s3-amazonaws-com-bucket-name/29661795

Comment: Perfect one of the comments there helped me. But this now works for GET requests along, not POST requests.