# PHP. Amazon S3 Signature V4. Simple example

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I my PHP application i used simple set of functions to upload to amazon S3.
My code uses Signature version 2. It all worked fine. But it doesn't work for new regions where signature V2 is not supported.

I try to implement signature V4 but it looks too complex. I just can not make working example for signature V4.

There is support of V4 sign in AWS SDK for PHP . But it is too complex for me. I can not use that SDK (because of PHP 5.2 and i can not upgrade it)

In my current code i have simple code for V2

```
$stringToSign="PUT\n\n$contentType\n$httpDate\nx-amz-acl:$acl\n";
$stringToSign.="/$resource";
$signature = $this->constructSig($stringToSign);
$req->addHeader("Authorization", "AWS " . $this->accessKeyId . ":" . $signature);

function constructSig($str) {
    $hasher = new Crypt_HMAC($this->secretKey, "sha1");
    $signature = $this->hex2b64($hasher->hash($str));
    return($signature);
}
```

Is it possible to have such simple constructSigV4 function to create new signature type?

Also, i see, it is needed to have bucket region for new type signature. If i don't know bucket region then what to do? Request bucket region each time before doing a request? I have buckets in different regions.

**Update.**

Simple example is there https://github.com/chrismeller/awstools/blob/master/aws/signature/v4.php

I seems created the working example. Signature seems passed. I got errors like "Signature doesn't match". I then corrected till this error gone.
But now i have other error:

Amazon response is :

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MissingContentLength</Code><Message>You must provide the Content-Length HTTP header.</Message>
```

But Content-Length is included in my request

```
PUT /259001/checkmark-circle.png HTTP/1.1
Host: ******.s3.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 2338
x-amz-acl: private
x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
X-AMZ-Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 07:33:01 -0500
Date: Tue, 19 Jan 2016 07:33:01 -0500
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=************/20160119/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-acl;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=c2bb290f2d54d31bc95785705530e10e0a8bde4c7b7dd1ef3b11a8fa7d96a57c
```

what can be wrong? Why it says Content-Length is missed if it is present?

Answer (score 3):

See [Retrieve bucket's objects without knowing bucket's region with AWS S3 REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27091816/retrieve-buckets-objects-without-knowing-buckets-region-with-aws-s3-rest-api/27092765#27092765) for how to learn the region of any bucket.  tl;dr: you can ask any region of S3 to give you the location of a bucket, or you can use information embedded in the error that occurs if the region was wrong.

Sqlbot's Best Practices for AWS, which is a book I haven't actually written (yet?), would tell you that the ideal solution for keeping track of each bucket's location is to canonicalize every S3 URI that you store with the appropriate regional hostname.  For a bucket called `example` in `us-west-2`, valid URLs include these:

```
https://example.s3.amazonaws.com/
https://example.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/
```

Both of these will send requests to the correct region, because the first form `*.s3.amazonaws.com` uses DNS managed by S3 itself to automatically send requests to the correct regional endpoint, while the second form explicitly includes the regional endpoint in the hostname.  Since there are consistent patterns across regions, you can relatively easily extract the correct region from the hostname if you internally store your URLs this way.

N.B. The exception to the above is the `us-east-1` region, which expects either `s3.amazonaws.com` or `s3-external-1.amazonaws.com` in the hostname, for legacy reasons.  Your code will need to handle this case.

Short of maintaining a configuration table of bucket-to-region mappings, storing S3 object references in this form is probably the best way to handle the region-specific authentication required by Signature Version 4.

At first glance, Signature V4 does look substantially more complicated than V2, and indeed, the signing code isn't as compact as what you've shown for V2, but if you managed to get V2 working, I'm confident that you can get V4 working.

There is an official Signature Version 4 Test Suite which you should find very useful -- it gives you several sets of input (request) parameters, the correct end result, and perhaps most importantly, **it gives you the results of the intermediate signing steps**, so that you can isolate which section of your implementation is not generating the correct values for use in subsequent steps.  Almost by definition, any slight error in your implementation of a signing algorithm will generate wildly incorrect results, which makes it difficult to pinpoint what you may be doing wrong.  The test suite should definitely help you get your code on track.

The notable difference between V2 and V4 is that V4 involves creation of a *signing key*, which uses your secret key, the service, region, and date, and this signing key is used instead of using the secret key directly when ultimately signing the request.

V4 is, at first glance, a bit intimidating and likely to conjure responses of "it wasn't broken, so why did they fix it?" but V4 introduces security enhancements that make it a much more secure mechanism in general, and -- I'm speculating, here -- provides enhanced security for your credentials within the AWS infrastructure.  How AWS has implemented it internally is not public information, but the logical construction of V4 shows that it prevents the individual AWS regions and services from needing to be in possession of your secret key.  Within AWS, a given service only needs access to your signing key for a given date, region, and service, in order to authenticate your requests, which means AWS appears to have implemented V4 at least partially with an eye toward an *internal* application of the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) in their own infrastructure... which is commendable.

Comment: I have got signature working. But i now have other problem. Do you have any ideas? (please, see my update)

Comment: This is bordering on being a different question, but I suspect the error message here is a little bit imprecise.  Using `x-amz-content-sha256: STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD` makes the signing and upload process more complicated -- not less -- and requires you to use a modified form of chunked transfer encoding, counting bytes and generating intermediate signatures.  See       http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-streaming.html.  You would be better off calculating the proper signature with the correct `x-amz-content-sha256` for the object you are uploading.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try to learn chunked transfer  and use it. I can not calculate hash of a file as i don't know a file body when upload starts. I read a file from stream and i can not read it 2 times.