# How to explicitly specify S3 region using JClouds?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kotlin, jclouds

I'm using jclouds and trying to abstract away S3 access. However, when attempting to get an object I get the following exception:

`org.jclouds.aws.AWSResponseException: request GET https://test-itpx.s3.amazonaws.com/marcel-mini.jpeg HTTP/1.1 failed with code 400, error: AWSError{requestId='0FB8701BF3CE81EB', requestToken='XXX', code='AuthorizationHeaderMalformed', message='The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-1'', context='{Region=eu-west-1, HostId=XXX=}'}`

By the looks of it S3 needs an explicit region definition and [answers such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27092765/7116844) suggest to explicitly define it.

Unfortunately, the blob context builder offers no way to specify the region. The way I define the context is:

```
 val context = ContextBuilder.newBuilder("aws-s3")
                .credentials("access_key", "access_secret")
                .buildView(BlobStoreContext::class.java)
```

And the object get is a simple `getBlob`:

`context.storageContext.getBlob(source.bucket, source.key)`

Is there a way to do explicitly define an s3 region / location with jclouds?

I'm using jclouds-allblobstore version 2.1.2.

Comment: jclouds should automatically detect the bucket region then change the endpoint and signature.  Could you run your test again with trace-level logging?  Also this might be easier to discuss on [jclouds JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JCLOUDS/issues).

Comment: I'm a bit embarrassed but a system restart seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look at the logs and follow up on their JIRA if the issue persists.

Comment: There is actually a difference in behavior between buckets created recently vs. ones created more than 24 hours ago so this may explain part of the issue.  If you can reproduce these symptoms please let me know.

Comment: OK, I just deployed the code to lambda and generated its own IAM role. And guess what - issue appeared again. Then I decided to hardcode previous IAM credentials - and voila, fixed. So issue might be related to recently IAM credentials after all. Is this something I should report somewhere?

Comment: The [jclouds jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JCLOUDS/issues) is the canonical place to report issues.